Mount problems with secondary encrypted btrfs disks after upgrade (Kubuntu 24.10)
After upgrading to Kubuntu 24.10 yesterday, mounting my encrypted btrfs disks during boot no longer works. The system/primary boot disk, which is also encrypted, is not affected. The disks can be mounted manually via a terminal without any problems and are usable then. As the same thing happened to me with the 24.04 upgrade, I now have to investigate the cause; last time only a new installation helped, this time I had to use Timeshift.
Unfortunately, many help instructions deal with an encrypted boot partition, but it works for me. I have tried many of the suggested solutions from various sources (updating grub, rebuilding initramfs, keyfile pattern in configuration etc) but none of them have had any effect.
Before I try to install the upgrade again, I would be very grateful for any suggestions!
My steps
I have upgraded the system according to the official instructions.
After the upgrade, I restarted the system. The system started, the Grub menu appeared and I selected Kubuntu. I was prompted to enter the password for LUKS; that also worked. The system disk can be unlocked without any problems.
After that, however, the system locked up for 90 seconds because it cannot mount the btrfs disks (on which /home is also located). It then boots up to the login screen. The 90-second timeout can be fixed by commenting out the two btrfs entries in fstab.
fstab
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
#UUID=965E-2AC0                            /boot/efi      vfat    defaults   0 2
UUID=dc5dea20-a27c-4d6b-af94-eb475db79f3f /boot          ext4    defaults   0 2
/dev/mapper/luks-c1e3cbb8-73d0-49e8-b173-59455bb7279d /              ext4    defaults   0 1
/swapfile                                 swap           swap    defaults   0 0
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0

# SSD Storage Pool
UUID=8429c8ad-62be-4298-8326-7f202187a03e /mnt/xxxxx_ssd btrfs defaults,noatime,autodefrag,compress=zstd 0 2

# HDD Storage Pool
UUID=6f9a885d-d08f-4684-a979-223d1e9c4edc /mnt/xxxxx_hdd btrfs defaults,noatime,autodefrag,compress=zstd 0 2

# Raspberry PI (WebDAV)
https://192.168.100.99/xxxxx-webdav    /mnt/xxxxx_ssd/home/xxxxx/.mounts/xxxxx-raspi      davfs   noauto,user,rw  0 0
https://192.168.100.99/transfer-webdav /mnt/xxxxx_ssd/home/xxxxx/.mounts/transfer-raspi   davfs   noauto,user,rw  0 0

# Bind HOME
/mnt/xxxxx_ssd/home /home none bind

UUID=965E-2AC0  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

crypttab
# <name>               <device>                         <password> <options>
luks-c1e3cbb8-73d0-49e8-b173-59455bb7279d UUID=c1e3cbb8-73d0-49e8-b173-59455bb7279d     none

# SSD Storage Pool
xxxxx_ssd_1 UUID=79c67ffa-70f5-4f7c-ae48-7a6a8b2f909b /etc/storagekeys/xxxxx_ssd.key luks,noearly,discard
xxxxx_ssd_2 UUID=7534ad5d-094e-4259-aaa5-1fa1e63b5a21 /etc/storagekeys/xxxxx_ssd.key luks,noearly,discard

# HDD Storage Pool
xxxxx_hdd_1 UUID=0525c36c-6ff2-4a42-9b8b-edc21ca62f31 /etc/storagekeys/xxxxx_hdd.key luks,noearly
xxxxx_hdd_2 UUID=e0a7ae73-e13f-492f-82ad-3c2a9dff75f3 /etc/storagekeys/xxxxx_hdd.key luks,noearly

Output of blkid
/dev/mapper/luks-c1e3cbb8-73d0-49e8-b173-59455bb7279d: LABEL="kubuntu_2404" UUID="93370c80-cb8b-4b5d-9da5-8139400a5361" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: LABEL="kubuntu_boot" UUID="dc5dea20-a27c-4d6b-af94-eb475db79f3f" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="kubuntu_boot" PARTUUID="c91f9fe9-a67f-4d01-a6c1-333cf0bed36a"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="WinSystem" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="54FC642DFC640C14" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="5fdf9496-8daf-4df1-9887-4a63e2d93f59"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="965E-2AC0" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="9ce15353-1e7e-44b6-856b-496df47550b9"
/dev/nvme0n1p6: UUID="c1e3cbb8-73d0-49e8-b173-59455bb7279d" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTLABEL="kubuntu_2404" PARTUUID="14b68a26-8039-4ae8-b156-617e92a81c18"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="6408A54608A51856" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="9d67681d-9424-4785-b5a8-b67e5d77a4e2"
/dev/sdd: UUID="7534ad5d-094e-4259-aaa5-1fa1e63b5a21" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
/dev/sdb: UUID="79c67ffa-70f5-4f7c-ae48-7a6a8b2f909b" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
/dev/sdc: UUID="e0a7ae73-e13f-492f-82ad-3c2a9dff75f3" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
/dev/sda: UUID="0525c36c-6ff2-4a42-9b8b-edc21ca62f31" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"

Output of lsblk
sda                                             8:0    0   1,8T  0 disk  
└─xxxxx_hdd_1                                 252:3    0   1,8T  0 crypt /mnt/xxxxx_hdd
sdb                                             8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk  
└─xxxxx_ssd_1                                 252:4    0 465,7G  0 crypt /home
                                                                         /mnt/xxxxx_ssd
sdc                                             8:32   0   1,8T  0 disk  
└─xxxxx_hdd_2                                 252:1    0   1,8T  0 crypt 
sdd                                             8:48   0 465,8G  0 disk  
└─xxxxx_ssd_2                                 252:2    0 465,7G  0 crypt 
nvme0n1                                       259:0    0 931,5G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1                                   259:1    0   100M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2                                   259:2    0    16M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p3                                   259:3    0 499,2G  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p4                                   259:4    0   783M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p5                                   259:5    0     4G  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p6                                   259:6    0 427,4G  0 part  
  └─luks-c1e3cbb8-73d0-49e8-b173-59455bb7279d 252:0    0 427,4G  0 crypt /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                                                         /


If further configurations or files are required, I will be happy to provide them.

I think I have found an answer to my problem in the depths of the Kubuntu bug tracker: Only single LUKS device unlocked on boot.
It describes my problem quite precisely. The solution confirmed there several times is the installation of the systemd-cryptsetup packages:
apt-get -y install systemd-cryptsetup
I will try to upgrade to 24.10 again today and test the solution. Afterwards I will give feedback here.
Update
I can confirm that the linked solution worked for me. I did the following in detail:

follow the official upgrade instructions (I used the console: sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop).
as soon as the upgrade has completed, do NOT restart the computer yet, but open a terminal.
now execute the following command: apt-get -y install systemd-cryptsetup.
now restart the computer -> works: everything is mounted as it should be.


thx, I have exactly the same problem. I have a second disk encrypted and mounted as /home.

See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1529983/the-luks-passphrase-screen-doesnt-show-up-after-24-10-installation
