The LUKS passphrase screen doesn't show up after 24.10 installation

The LUKS passphrase screen does not appear after installing Kubuntu 24.10. I have attempted a fresh installation, but it was unsuccessful. Also changing the boot screen in KDE settings doen't do anything.
Below are my fstab and crypttab files:
# /etc/crypttab: mappings for encrypted partitions.
#
# Each mapped device will be created in /dev/mapper, so your /etc/fstab
# should use the /dev/mapper/<name> paths for encrypted devices.
#
# See crypttab(5) for the supported syntax.
#
# NOTE: You need not list your root (/) partition here, but it must be set up
#       beforehand by the initramfs (/etc/mkinitcpio.conf). The same applies
#       to encrypted swap, which should be set up with mkinitcpio-openswap
#       for resume support.
#
# <name>               <device>                         <password> <options>
cryptHome     UUID=e2652883-XXXX-4d1b-XXXX-c842019fb8d9    none    luks,timeout=30

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=1442-DF7D                            /boot/efi      vfat    defaults   0 2
UUID=3025d2f2-1e29-464a-a7f8-bd1a5a6c9830 /              ext4    defaults   0 1
/swapfile                                 swap           swap    defaults   0 0
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
/dev/mapper/cryptHome         /home    ext4   defaults    0    2

journalctl -xb doesn't show any errors related to LUKS, nor the /var/log/syslog. Everything works perfectly when I manually decrypt and mount my partition to /home. However, I'm unsure how to resolve the issue with the automatic decryption. Please help!

I managed to solve the problem by running:
$ sudo apt-get -y install systemd-cryptsetup
Look: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/2084251

Thanks! It solved my problem.
